# Two smooth manifolds without boundaries with the same universal cover and fundamental group are diffeomorphic?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

As in the title, I was wondering if that's true or not. If it's true it seems quite odd, but on the other hand I'm not able to find a counterexample.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, a Googling of the phrase "exotic spheres" might answer your question.

Comment: This answered indeed to my question. And I wonder: in lower dimension is still false? Normally if the counterexample provided is in such strange space is because in low dimension it's true.

Comment: What do you mean "with the same covering space"? Universal cover? 3-manifolds are indeed largely determined by their fundamental group, though lens spaces (e.g. L(7,1), L(7,2)) give counterexamples. Past 3 dimensions there are massive numbers of counterexamples. Fake tori (I think you can even change the homeomorphism type!) abound in dimensions $n \geq 5$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was speaking about the universal cover indeed. A lapsus.

Comment: Dimension $3$ is complicated, but manifolds with multiple smooth structures are plentiful in dimension $4$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2129843/uncountable-differential-structures-on-4-manifolds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The space $S^2 \times S^3$ is a double cover of $M = S^2\times \mathbb{RP}^3$ and $N = \mathbb{RP}^2 \times S^3$, but they're not even homotopy equivalent (they have different $H^2$, for example).